# Project config only partially syncing

Tags: craft3, projectconfig, project.yaml

Not sure if this belongs here but decided to post it after all...

I've set up a craft site (Version 3.3.x) and since we're about to add more sites to it etc, we decided to start using a project config to keep everything & everyone synced.

So per the documentation, I started out of our production site, enabled the `useProjectConfigFile` setting and used the cli command to build it properly, than I continued by taking a database backup and setting that backup up on our dev/staging envs.

I copied the project config to our dev env, did some changes (added a new site & sitegroup, enabled some sections for the new site) and when I tried to apply these changes to our staging env, they only partially get applied and I get the following error:

`Applying changes from project.yaml ... error: Undefined index: 684d2471-bc50-4aa2-b59c-e174e8250d74`

When I run the project config sync command again after that, it gives no error or so but it still did not apply the changes.

I looked in to the project.yml file for that key and it is the key for the primary site, that was unchanged.

I'd really like to keep using the project config, but I've got the feeling I missed a step somewhere or so because it only applies the changes partially.

Let me know if any extra information is desired.

Comment: We're having the exact same issue. @mrsmn did you ever find a solution to this problem?

Comment: We have the same issues here. Syncing projectConfig works with 7 of 10 updates, but the remaining 3 updates ... -either cause errors -do not sync changes -or even worse: sync changes in a faulty way We re-evaluate projectConfig approximately every third project and always end up going back to making structural changes on the qs/live system and then bringing them back to DEV with dumps. I don't even remember how often we manually had to rebuild structures and configurations. Really frustrating.